# What is the syntax error in this sql snippet?

Tags: php, syntax

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect(`localhost`, `username`, `password`); 
if (!$link) {   
    die(`Could not connect: ` . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo `Connected successfully`; 
mysql_select_db(ebe);

?>
```

I went through the above SQL snippet a bunch of times but for some reason i cant figure out the error. I have tried changing the quotes from '' to `` but it hasn't worked either.

Comment: Please tell me you didn't just post your database username/password.

Comment: What error is displayed?

Comment: This question is horribly misclassified.  This should be tagged with `php` not `sql`, as it looks like a code problem!

Answer (score 3):

The back-tick characters are special to PHP. They run the string inside the back-ticks as a shell command.

Read the doc here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Use single-quotes or double-quotes in PHP for string literal delimiters.

PS: There are other problems in your code, as commented by @fvu. You're using the deprecated mysql extension (you should be using PDO). You have a word `ebe` which looks like you're using it like a PHP constant. Not sure if you intend this to be a string or a variable.

Comment: Don't forget the highly suspicious `ebe` and the deprecated mysql_ extension... Not to mention that there's no sql in sight in the question.